# How to remove report folder from being shared to a certain user?

Tags: reporting, reports-folder

In our salesforce org we have enabled "enhanced reporting". When I share a report folder with an individual user it works, but I want to know how can I remove the share?  I can make someone a "Viewer, Editor, or Manager", but there doesn't seem to be an option to remove the share.

Comment: u shd see a x icon next to the share line item.. clicking that will remove the share..

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't see the "x".  If I click the report folder, and then go to "Share", the window comes up and shows the shares, one line item for each share, but that's it.  You can change to Viewer, Editor, or Manager", but no way to remove the share.

Comment: Sorry, missed it.  there is an "x", it's just very faint.  Thanks @VamsiKrishna

Answer (score 0):

The "X" is only visible if you hover on the right side of the line for each share. If you don't hover you'll never know it's there.

Example:

[image: Folder Share x not visible]

[image: Folder Share x visible]